# Centering Fixed top menu Ul

Tags: css

im trying to centering the ul menu in center but isnt working, the menu is sticky fixed menu, hope someone can find a solution in centeriong my top menu in the page.

Here is the link do take look

```
http://jsfiddle.net/pMBfD/
```

or

```
http://maurobonucci.com/demo/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this seems to work on jsfiddle.

```
ul#menu { 
float: none; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0 auto;
```

Update using CodePen instead of jsfiddle
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DxnjH/

Comment: Are you sure that this worked in jfille? I see no effect

Comment: see this one, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DxnjH/. Due to small screen on jsfiddle so its not noticeable properly.

Comment: yes, i see, so the problem was just in the "margin: 0 auto; "

Comment: Yes, margin:0 auto; is the way to center div tags. Also you were floating the menu to the left that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but here's my suggestion:

I took a look at some of your css code...

```
ul#menu { 
   float: left; 
   list-style: none; 
   margin: 0px 0px 0 0px; 
   width:700px;
   }
```

To center any div nowadays, you should use something like `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`, giving you a centered element/div with a top and bottom margin of 0. Apply this to the menu and it should come out centered. Hope I could help!